Execute function within my plugin, through a twig (Admin page) template
I have created a (private) plugin, ginacpmods. The main class is called GinaCp which extends Plugin.
The plugin has an admin page which is rendered with templates/index.twig. This twig file contains a button which, will execute craft.ginacpmods.clearAll(). This doesn't work. All I get back is
Calling unknown method: craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable::ginacpmods()
I've tried referencing ginacp, ginacpmods, _ginacpmods but neither works. I'm starting to wonder what I'm missing.
The function I'm calling is dead simple right now and doesn't really do anything yet:
plugins/ginacpmods/src/GinaCp.php:
class GinaCp extends Plugin {
    [...]

    public function clearAll(): bool|array|string {
        return 'Done.';
    }

Is there something I need to do in order to expose the clearAll() function to twig?

Turns out I was missing the crucial part of exposing the class to twig itself. I didn't know I had to do that.
So the solution ended up being to add this to the plugin init:
Event::on(
    CraftVariable::class,
    CraftVariable::EVENT_INIT,
    function (Event $event) {
        $variable = $event->sender;
        $variable->set('ginacpmods', GinaCp::class);
    }
);

